# Marmalade deploy - deployment.py, line 62, in SetOpt

Tags: python, xcode, deployment, marmalade

I got a mac book pro retina and I'am trying to create a project from the .mkb file: but I got this error

```
Building project: /Users/sergioandreotti/Downloads/twins/template/marmalade/FeedtheTwins.mkb
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Developer/Marmalade/6.1/s3e/makefile_builder/mkb.py", line 209, in <module>
    run()
  File "/Developer/Marmalade/6.1/s3e/makefile_builder/mkb.py", line 137, in run
    main(sys.argv)
  File "/Developer/Marmalade/6.1/s3e/makefile_builder/mkb.py", line 32, in main
    exit_code = mkb_main.run(argv)
  File "/p4/sdkbuild/sdk/main/s3e/makefile_builder/mkb_main.py", line 3461, in run
  File "/p4/sdkbuild/sdk/main/s3e/makefile_builder/mkb_main.py", line 3619, in run2
  File "/p4/sdkbuild/sdk/main/s3e/makefile_builder/mkb_main.py", line 2697, in process_mkb_for_platform
  File "/p4/sdkbuild/sdk/main/s3e/makefile_builder/mkb_main.py", line 690, in process
  File "/p4/sdkbuild/sdk/main/s3e/makefile_builder/mkb_main.py", line 2602, in process_file
  File "/p4/sdkbuild/sdk/main/s3e/makefile_builder/mkb_main.py", line 2124, in process
  File "/p4/sdkbuild/sdk/main/s3e/makefile_builder/mkb_main.py", line 2124, in <lambda>
  File "/p4/sdkbuild/sdk/main/s3e/makefile_builder/mkb_main.py", line 1971, in process
  File "/p4/sdkbuild/sdk/main/s3e/makefile_builder/mkb_main.py", line 1130, in process_deployment_line
  File "/p4/sdkbuild/sdk/main/s3e/makefile_builder/deployment.py", line 62, in SetOpt
NameError: global name 'output' is not defined
Press enter to continue...
```

I ve found this solution: https://devnet.madewithmarmalade.com/questions/2784/mkb-fails-to-build.html

but I don't think it's the best solution.

it's working for building the project but I got other problems when I have to deploy with the Marmalade deploy tool.

Sometimes deploy fails and the error in the error log is the same "global name 'output' is not defined"

I m not able to save my configuration in the .mkb, because if I do this, next time I reload the configuration, the deploy fails.

Answer (score 0):

it was my fault, I had marmalade 6.1.1 installed instead of 6.1.2.

6.1.1 doensn't provide retina support and in the .mkb there was the tag "Enable 4-inch Retina Support" set.